# Automapper AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I am getting a peculiar error with Automapper

Error messages:

```
Mapping types:
TransportOffer -> TransportOfferDto
Model.TransportOffer -> Dto.TransportOfferDto

Type Map configuration:
TransportOffer -> TransportOfferDto
Model.TransportOffer -> Dto.TransportOfferDto

Property:
FromCity ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
City -> CityDto
Model.City -> Dto.CityDto

Type Map configuration:
City -> CityDto
Model.City -> Dto.CityDto

Property:
Country ---> System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Add' in type 'Proxy_System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Dto.CountryDto, BusinessLogic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]__17474517' from assembly 'AutoMapper.Proxies, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005' does not have an implementation.
```

Below are my entities and DTO and the query that retrieves the data.
I am using Automapper 7.0.1 and Automapper.Attributes 6.0.1

I have tried also with custom mapping configuration and the error is the same.

Here is the Automapper custom property configuration:

```
Mapper.Initialize
(
    config =>
    {
        config.CreateMap<TransportOfferDto, TransportOffer>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FromCity, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.FromCity))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FromCountry, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.FromCountry))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ToCity, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.ToCity))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ToCountry, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.ToCountry));
         }
     );
```

> Country - entity:

```
public class Country : BaseEntity<Int32>
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Capital { get; set; }
    public Int32 TotalSold { get; set; }
}
```

> CountryDto

```
[MapsTo(typeof(Country))]
[MapsFrom(typeof(Country))]
public class CountryDto : EntityDto<Int32>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Capital { get; set; }
    public Int32 TotalSold { get; set; }
}
```

> City - entity:

```
public class City : BaseEntity<Int32>
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 CountryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

> CityDto

```
[MapsTo(typeof(City))]
[MapsFrom(typeof(City))]
public class CityDto : EntityDto<Int32>
{
    public Int32 CountryID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CountryDto> Country { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

> TransportOffer - entity:

```
public class TransportOffer : BaseEntity<Guid>
{
    public Guid TransportToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Int32 FromCityID { get; set; }
    public  virtual City FromCity { get; set; }
    public Int32 FromCountryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Country FromCountry { get; set; }
    public Int32 ToCityID { get; set; }
    public virtual City ToCity { get; set; }
    public Int32 ToCountryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Country ToCountry { get; set; }
}
```

> TransportOfferDto:

```
[MapsTo(typeof(TransportOffer))]
[MapsFrom(typeof(TransportOffer))]
public class TransportOfferDto : EntityDto<Guid>
{
    public Guid TransportToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }    
    public Int32 FromCityID { get; set; }
    public virtual CityDto FromCity { get; set; }       
    public Int32 FromCountryID { get; set; }
    public virtual CountryDto FromCountry { get; set; } 
    public Int32 ToCityID { get; set; }
    public virtual CityDto ToCity { get; set; }
    public Int32 ToCountryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Country ToCountry { get; set; }
}
```

> Query

```
var query = Repository.GetAll()
            .Include(x => x.FromCountry)
            .Include(x => x.FromCity)
            .Include(x => x.ToCountry)
            .Include(x => x.ToCity)
            .Where(p => p.MembershipID == input).ToList();

return ObjectMapper.Map<List<TransportOfferDto>>(query);
```

Comment: You probably need to show us the remaining DTOs as well.

Comment: Did you create a mapping for Country and City?

Comment: I'm guessing you have somewhere a map for ICollection :)

Comment: @V0ldek  - that is the complete DTO it is a mapping table.

Comment: @MelGerats - The mapping for country and city is made the same way as MapsFrom/MapsTo with automapper attributes

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu - No I dont have mapping for ICollection

Comment: `public virtual ICollection<CountryDto>` you do

Comment: @MelGerats - Yes you're right, I forgot, Do i need to add specific ICollection mapping in the automapper configuration?

Comment: You don't, Automapper is smart enough to map an `ICollection<From>` to an `ICollection<To>`.
But it won't automatically map an object to a collection of objects, see Mel Gerats answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your CityDto class has a collection of Countries

```
[MapsTo(typeof(City))] [MapsFrom(typeof(City))] 
public class CityDto : EntityDto<Int32> 
{ 
    public Int32 CountryID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CountryDto> Country { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

But your City class has a single Country.

```
public class City : BaseEntity<Int32>
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 CountryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

How are you mapping them?

Comment: I am not mapping them anyhow
I think that the DTO it should be without the ICollection??!!

Comment: I think so too!

Comment: Got it working, the ICollection was the problem, it somehow got c/p from another class...

Thank you all.

Comment: And you actually have an ICollection map. That happens because CreateMissingTypeMaps is true. Setting it to false would make things easier to understand.